# Windows 10 can't boot after encryption

Tags: windows-10, boot, disk-encryption, acer-aspire, diskcryptor

I used diskcryptor to encryption my C: drive, the process is done by using default encryption setting. However my Acer aspire v nitro laptop won't boot and stuck at the attempting repair screen. I tried to run the command chkdsk in cmd but it shows that my C: is not accessible (which is normal due to encryption), but the problem is, my laptop won't boot up and how can I remove the encryption and get my laptop back to normal.

Please help me, I know I sound desperate as that is my only device that I used for my work, any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: The company website suggests that you create a DiskCryptor LiveCD/LiveUSB disk/stick to boot from. Then start up DiskCryptor by booting from the LiveCD/LiveUSB, then decrypt the drive.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to plug the disk to another PC, and use DiskCryptor to decrypt the disk. Or you need a bootable Windows disk that you create with DiskCryptor included.